# Hyperlink's click function is not available after rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, html-sanitizing

I do some string manipulations and wanna create a string like below. [sample] and [express] are hyperlinks.

[image]

`<a>` element should have `click` function and it should call `searchFromURL()`. 
But once it is rendered, the `click` function is not available, what might be the reason behind that?

Or is there any other way to accomplish this?

**home.page.html**
`<ion-row innerHTML="{{buildNavigationSearchElement(dicDat.translation)}}"></ion-row>`

**home.page.ts**

```
buildNavigationSearchElement(elementText: String){
    let retElem = elementText + '<a href="#" (click)="searchFromURL();">Search Text</a>';
    return retElem;
  }
```

Is there a safest way to build this element with `click` function?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with this solution. As follows the hyperlink is generated.

**home.page.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="buildNavigationSearchElement()"></div>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
buildNavigationSearchElement(){
let myText = This is a + '<a class="myhyperlink_1">sample</a>' + text to + '<a class="myhyperlink_2">express</a>' + my issue.
return myText;
}
```

Inside `ngAfterViewChecked()` event each and every hyperlink is bound to a class method.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
   var myElements = 
   this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[class^="myhyperlink"]');
   var i: number;
   for (i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
       myElements[i].addEventListener('click', this.openAlert.bind(this));
   }
}
```

Property array is stored in class with actions and parameters for each hyperlinks.

```
openAlert(parameter: any) {
   let className = parameter.srcElement.className;
   //do what ever required
}
```